# Como cria uma função em javascript para filtrar rss de audio(podcast) dpara um projeto?

Tags: javascript, html5, xml, html5-audio, xmlhttprequest

Tenho uma duvida, referente a como cria uma função onde posso filtrar o áudio(.mp3),com uma quantidade máxima de 5 áudios do feed.

E titulo do áudio do feed RSS da parte do podcast da CBN:
http://imagens.globoradio.globo.com/cbn/podcast/cardapios/tecnologia.xml

Pois,neste caso consegui colocar o href, mas tenho que coloca um a um, e depois coloca o titulo do podcast uma a um que está puxando.
Estou criando um projeto de website de acessibilidade para deficiente visuais com recurso de noticias via áudio através do podcast.

utilizo uma framework de áudio com playlist chamada: audiojs(kolber.github.io/audiojs)[image: imagem do projeto])

Comment: poderia simplificar a explicação, não entendi muito bem, você quer filtrar/baixar 5 áudios da podcast da CBN ?

Comment: Exato,Thiago. Quero filtrar o áudio  do podcast da cbn.  O que devo fazer ? Obrigado . Duvidas ,olhe a framework de audio que coloquei na pergunta acima. na parte de playlist.

Comment: entendi Carlos, realmente nunca fiz isso, mas vou ver se consigo algo.

Comment: valeu,Thiago. Olha encontrei um recurso que atualmente estou tentando trabalhar para criar esse filtro seria google feed API.  Deste já agradeço.

Comment: realmente pelo que vi acho que esse seria o melhor recuros Carlos

Comment: Certo,Thiago. Estou vendo,mas será que posso integrar com audiojs.

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se a resposta lhe ajudou? Se não, informe poderia teve alguma duvida no uso dela.

Comment: Boa noite,ajudou muito.Mas tenho um novo desafio a respeito do podcast como posso joga o arquivo xml, em um banco de dados(lembrando que a função que puxa Feed é Ajax) pra criar um histórico dessas noticias, e o player acessa esse banco de dados, é toca a noticia.

Answer (score 1):

O dominio do `.globo.com` suporta `Cross-Origin`, conforme a resposta do header ao acessar o endereço http://imagens.globoradio.globo.com/cbn/podcast/cardapios/tecnologia.xml:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

Note o `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`, isto significa que qualquer domínio diferente de `imagens.globoradio.globo.com` poderá usar o xml, portanto você pode usar ajax pra isto.

> CORS e um requisito necessário pra acessar paginas de diferentes domínios com ajax por exemplo

No exemplo na pagina http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test6.html é necessário criar uma lista com  pra criar a playlist, com base nisto criei um código em javascript puro pra usar com o audio.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    audio.hide {/*oculta o player padrao do browser*/
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<audio class="hide" controls="controls"></audio>
<ol id="playlistitems"></ol>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function retrieveData(rss, maxItens) {/*extrai dados do feed*/
        var items = rss.getElementsByTagName("item");
        var current, title;
        var playList = [];
        var j = items.length;

        if (maxItens > 0 && maxItens < j) {
            j = maxItens;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            current = items[i].getElementsByTagName("enclosure");
            title   = items[i].getElementsByTagName("title");

            if (current.length > 0) {
                playList.push({
                    "url": current[0].getAttribute("url"),
                    "title": title[0].textContent
                });
            }
        }

        return playList;
    }

    function audioJS(items, total) {/*cria o player com audio.js*/
        var allAudios, current = 0, audio;
        allAudios = audiojs.createAll({
            "trackEnded": function() {
                current++;
                if (current < total) {
                    audio.load(items[current].getAttribute("data-href"));
                    audio.play();
                }
            }
        });

        audio = allAudios[0];
        audio.load(items[0].getAttribute("data-href"));
        audio.play();

        for (var i = 0, j = items.length; i < j; i++) {
            items[i].onclick = function() {
                audio.load(this.getAttribute("data-href"));
                audio.play();
                return false;
            };
        }
    }

    function init(data, maxItens) {/*cria os links*/
        var playList = retrieveData(data, maxItens);
        var el, li, playListItems = document.getElementById("playlistitems");

        if (playList.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0, j = playList.length; i < j; i++) {
                li = document.createElement("li");
                el = document.createElement("a");
                el.setAttribute("href", "#");
                el.setAttribute("data-href", playList[i].url);
                el.innerHTML = playList[i].title;

                li.appendChild(el);
                playListItems.appendChild(li);
            }
        }

        if (j > 0) {
            audioJS(playListItems.getElementsByTagName("a"), j);
        }
    }

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://imagens.globoradio.globo.com/cbn/podcast/cardapios/tecnologia.xml";

    ajax.open("GET", url, true);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
            if (ajax.status === 200) {/*se tudo ok envia o feed pro evento init*/
                init(ajax.responseXML, 5);//O segundo parametro limita pra 5 itens no máximo
            } else {/*se falhar ao baixar o xml entao mostra o codigo do erro*/
                alert("Erro: " + ajax.status);
            }
        }
    };
    ajax.send(null);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este e apenas um exemplo simples, se quiser customizar mais use o exemplo do link que citei (que usa jquery).

Pra mudar o limite máximo de itens a ser exibido para 3 por exemplo, vá dentro do ajax, altere o segundo argumento da função `init`:

```
init(ajax.responseXML, 3);
```

Pra deixar sem limite remova o ultimo parâmetro:

```
init(ajax.responseXML);
```

Comment: Guilherme,Obrigado. Verifiquei seu código, e sim esta puxando o xml,mas quando rodo ele ,não vai para próxima faixa e não encontrei a parte onde eu posso reduzir o tamanho da playlist(limita-ló por exemplo:puxar só 3 notícias), pois o  código ele puxa todo o xml da página. Deste já Agradeço,Obrigado.

Comment: @CarlosHenrique Desculpe me esqueci disto, editei a resposta, veja se ajuda.

Comment: Agora entendi que a função Ajax gerencia a filtragem do Feed,Obrigado.     Mas no caso do player ir para o próximo áudio do Feed(função next),no caso do audiojs têm uma variável next  será que é isso que esta faltando no código. Pois  quando finaliza o player, ele não vai para o próximo audio , retorna para o mesmo, como se fosse um loop.

Comment: @CarlosHenrique você quer dizer no último audio?

Comment: Ele roda,quando está acabando o áudio,ele retorna no mesmo.

Comment: @CarlosHenrique Corrigi o código :)

Comment: @CarlosHenrique está faltando algumas funções no teu código. Você misturou duas coisas e você incluiu algumas coisas manualmente, eu não entendi bem aonde quer chegar.

Comment: essa é estrutura html do projeto:http://bit.ly/1NG4nJy. logo eu iria inserir base desse codigo na div de cada assunto. Deste já Agradeço. Qualquer coisa,posto a dúvida,Obrigado.

Comment: Antes de você responder está pergunta no stack, eu estava colocando manualmente os feed na div do player para que o mesmo puxa-se para tocar. Mas agora atravês da sua ajuda, conseguir automatizar isso.

Comment: Você viu a estrutura, na parte da div do player(<div id="wrapper">),logo abaixo aparecer a tag audio html5  com preload="auto", no caso posso mante-lá . para deixar totalmente automatizado meu player como acabou aquela noticia, vai para a próxima.assim sucessivamente.

Comment: @CarlosHenrique você viu que eu corrigi o código, era um problema no trackEnd, estava assim: `"trackEnded": function() {
current++;
if (current < total) {
audio.load(items[0].getAttribute("data-href"));
audio.play();
}
}`, mas o correto era isto: `"trackEnded": function() {
current++;
if (current < total) {
audio.load(items[current].getAttribute("data-href"));
audio.play();
}
}`, eu testei e funcionou, assim que uma faixa de audio termina ele vai pro proximo item.

Comment: Realizei as Alterações do feed ,e no CSS para deixar responsivo.(https://jsfiddle.net/6xops9cu)

Comment: @CarlosHenrique Desculpe, eu não estou entendendo, pensei que teu problema era com vincular o RSS com o `<audio>` e o audio.js, não entendo o que tem ser responsivo ou css tem haver com o problema, na verdade acredito que isto seja mais uma questão de "estética" e não o problema. Poderia me explicar exatamente o que falta pra ti?

Comment: Primeiramente, Desculpa pela confusão.E sim o problema do vínculo do RSS com audiojs ,Realizei as devidas alterações,Deu certo. Deste já Agradeço,Obrigado.

Comment: @CarlosHenrique não tem problema algum, só gostaria de saber se isto funcionou pra ti. Se faltar algo avise. Até mais.

Comment: Funcionou.Obrigado